# Decreasing execution time with sql left outer join query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

How can I decrease the execution time with this sql squery? it is taking over a minute to execute and return rows.(executed in Sql server management studio 2008)

```
if(@NotInvoiced =1)
BEGIN
Select @Command = 
'select Distinct C.FileID, C.FileName, convert(nvarchar,C.DateReported,111) AS ''DateReported'', 
C.FileDetailsPlainText, CFIT.Level3 as ''InvestigationType'', INV.FName + '' '' + INV.LName AS ''Name'', 
convert(nvarchar,DD,111) AS ''DD'', i.FirstName + '' '' + i.LastName AS ''ReportedBy''
from CaseFiles C 
join InvestigatorCaseFileAccess IA on C.FileID=IA.CaseFileID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN CaseFileTimeBills tb on C.FileID=tb.FileID
LEFT OUTER JOIN CaseFileExpenses e on C.FileID=e.FileID

left join Element07a_Persons i on i.PersonID = c.PersonID
LEFT OUTER JOIN CaseFileInvestigationTypes CFIT ON C.InvestigationTypeID = CFIT.InvestigationTypeID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Investigators INV ON C.InvestigatorID = INV.InvestigatorID
where (tb.InvNumber IS null OR e.InvNumber IS null) and Deleted=0 and IA.InvestigatorID=' + CONVERT (nvarchar(max),@InvestigatorID) + ' and IA.AllowAccess = ''True''
 and tb.FileID = C.FileID or e.FileID=C.FileID '
END
```

Comment: Can you post the execution plan?

Comment: This is pretty hard to answer without knowing anything about your schema.

Comment: As a side comment, you almost certainly want to add parentheses around `tb.FileID = C.FileID or e.FileID=C.FileID`. Right now your where clause is boiling down to "where all of these things are true, OR where e.FileID=C.FileID"

Comment: wow, just adding () around the "tb.FileID = C.FileID or e.FileID=C.FileID" trimmed it down from 1 min to 3 seconds

Comment: Yes, it cannot index OR conditions.  So when you parenthesized it, all the other AND conditions had a chance at using an index, Deleted=0, IA.AllowAccess = ''True''.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discovered in the comments, it looks like your problem was that you were missing parentheses around `tb.FileID = C.FileID or e.FileID=C.FileID`.

Adding those parentheses fundamentally changes the filtering semantics and therefore changes the data you get back. It's like your original query without the parentheses was returning gobs of data, or at the very least comparing every single possible row when it only needed to compare a few.

Marlin Pierce made the good observation that parenthesizing those ORs allows the DBMS to use utilize indices (for example for the condition `Deleted=0`), whereas before it could not.

Comment: Thank you. And thanks for Marlin Pierce.